# php redirect doesn't change the url

Tags: php, redirect, header

I know this is a very common question, but I could not find the answer

I'v a post.php, that submit a post form to controller.php
When it goes right, in controller it does:

```
header("Location: ./post?ok=1");
```

the post is actually inserted, and it goes through the line above,
but the url in the browser seems never changed, and at the end there is not the ok param,

I could use session variable to store such a success/failure param, but this way should be working

post.php:

```
<form action="controller" method="post">
    <input name="test" value='test' type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="post"  />
</form>
```

controller.php:

```
<?php
    header("Location: ./post?ok=1");
?>
```

Edit 1:

```
header("Refresh:1;url=http://localhost/test/post?ok=1"); //doesn't work better
```

Edit 2:

in post.php top I've put

```
debug("post l ".count($_POST));
debug("get l ".count($_GET));
```

they show 0's before submit, and 0's after also

edit3: it works

was blocked by:

```
if ($success){
    header("Location: ./post?ok=1");
}
header("Location: ./post");
```

that should be:

```
if ($success){
    header("Location: ./post?ok=1");
} else {
    header("Location: ./post");
}
```

thx all

Comment: I think you have not given ACTION of form tag properly... it should be something like <form action="controller.php" method="post"> You have missed extension of the file.

Comment: Are you sure the head function executed?

Comment: yes I'v put a debug('test') there

Comment: What is controller? in form action Plz give proper redirection link or remove if you want refresh current page.

Comment: "controller" -> controller.php it's not working better if I put .php in the form if that's u mean

Comment: Your "Edit 1" won't work at all you mixed up there a meta refresh redirect and a HTTP redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should not use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` this is unsafe. Also it is possible that the client won't send this header anyway. Right now I don't know how but I'm sure that this could be used to highjack your site for something evil.

Better you should know where the form data came from and redirect the user there back.

By the way your redirect maybe don't work like expected because the url already contain a questionmark. So you have to add more parameters with a `&` sign.

For the redirect I would suggest the HTTP `302 Found` response status. But you have to be sure that nothing other is send out before. There must be no HTML output or empty lines before this following `header` line:

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/your/source.form", true, 302);
```

Comment: I've put header("Location: ./post?ok"); and not working better, edited the question

Comment: In redirects it's better to use full urls relativ urls are *bad* there the browser can be confused with the source and the destination url. On which url should the redirect be relativ to?

Comment: I've tried either header("Location: http://localhost/test/post?ok=1"); and header("Refresh:0;url=http://localhost/test/post?ok=1"); not working yet

Comment: The first one should work you just have to confirm that nothing other will be send to the client before the header line. So just move that special line more upper.

Comment: damn u'r right, I must find what additioanl thigs made it fail, there are just some curl_exec(..); so it shouldn't fail, thx for the moment

Comment: the last 2 parameters saved my life so far. let's see if it will last longer than a cache time

Answer (score 3):

Try using the HTTP status code 303 See Oter:

```
header("Location: your/location", true, 303);
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be some problems on the server side (e.g. your code prints out something before setting the headers). In order to debug this, you need to set `display_errors = On` in your php.ini or temporarily enable it in your code with `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`.

In most of the cases, the error is `"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent."`. Make sure there's no `print`, `echo` or any white space and extra line after PHP closing tag (`?>`)

Comment: I did not get these errors, and controller is not echoing any html or anything there are just some php_curl calls and header() redirects

Answer (score 1):

This could a problem of a second redirect by the server.

```
header('Location: post.php?ok=1', true, 303);
exit;
```

Try to add the extension **.php** to the url, to make sure, that the **post?ok=1** is not redirected to **post.php** by the server (e.g. htaccess). In the additional redirect you could loose the get parameters. Then don't forget to add an exit after the header redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually... it appears you are not following the header() call with "exit".
Examples:

```
header( 'location: ' . $location ); exit;

header( 'location: ' . $location, true, 301 ); exit;
```

When you "exit" after the call, the URL is changed in the browser address bar because the code is prevented from continuing to execute. Otherwise, the code continues executing which causes the URL to remain unchanged.